# Way to get return type of a method in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ios, uikit

I'm writing a generic 'attribute/key editor' view class on iOS, and it checks the type of the editing key using `[objectForKey isKindOfClass:[NSDate class]]`, for example. I just ran into a wall when I realized that will fail if `objectForKey` is `nil`. Is there a way to get the class/return type for a generic Objective-C property, even if said property is `nil`? I know about `method_getReturnType` in the Objective-C run-time, but that sounds like overkill for what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can’t. Although return type information for methods is available, the return type encoding for methods which return objects is simply `@`, meaning “object reference”.

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking for doesn't make sense.

Remember that a name alone does not identify a method. Objects respond to those messages (or not); a method does not exist alone, only as part of an object (or class).

Having no object, you cannot tell from it what hypothetically sending a message to an object would return.

ETA: How is it that you could be editing the attributes of something, but not have the object to edit in order to examine its properties? It seems like you have a bug somewhere else.

> I know about `method_getReturnType` in the Objective-C run-time, but that sounds like overkill for what I need.

There are two ways. If you want to support informal properties (KVC-compliant accessor methods with no `@property` declaration), that's exactly what you need. If you only care about formal properties (`@property`), use [the `property_getAttributes` function](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/property_getAttributes).

Comment: He’s not saying the object being inspected is nil, but that the property value is nil.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just first check to make sure that objectForKey != nil, and the continue with the isKindOfClass checking? If you make sure that the object doesn't equal nil first you can easily check or safely exit without any failures.

Comment: very true, and probably what I have to do long term, if there's no solution here – but I'd like the user to be able to establish an object where there is none. for example, in this case, I'm building a data reporting system and initially had the start date and end date nil, so an easy fix to to just make them [NSDate date], but still, I'd like the flexibility.

Comment: i have no idea when != nil would prevent you from doing anything. unless you are trying to do some sort of super-reflection, in which case you those the wrong language for it

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where your data is coming from, but you might want to consider supplanting nil with NSNull and that will allow you to gain NSObject-like properties on something that is technically null

But the null check becomes more pain in the ass.

It goes from object != nil to

(NSNull *)object != [NSNull null]

Comment: That won't help, since `[NSNull null]` doesn't have the property to examine any more than `nil` does.

Comment: If you have to do the check a lot, you can always use a handy-dandy category: https://gist.github.com/707337

Comment: @peter but at least he would be able to do isKindOfClass ... i mean... I'm shooting the breeze here. I'm not sure anyone knows what the hell he is talking about.