# How can I check a property exists on an object using OCUnit/XCTest?

Tags: xcode, tdd, ocunit, xctest

I'm trying to further my experience with TDD, and I'd like to know how I can check if a property exists on a class. Specifically, I want to ensure the object has a double named accumulator.

```
//
//  CSCalculatorModel.h
//  Calculator
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CSCalculatorModel : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) double accumulator;

@end
```

I know I can use tests like the following for objects, but how do I test C scalars?

```
- (void)testExample
{
    XCTAssertNotNil(calculatorClass.accumulator, @"Accumulator property does not exist on calculator class");
}
```

Comment: Would it be appropriate to just check if it is 0? E.g. `XCTAssert(calculator.accumulator == 0.0, @"Accumulator property does not exist on calculator class");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To verify the property's existence, call +instancesRespondToSelector on your class to make sure the property's generated getter method exists:

```m
- (void)testExample {
    XCTAssertTrue([CSCalculatorModel instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(accumulator)], @"Accumulator property does not exist on calculator class");
}
```

[Peter Hosey's answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4230025/1914) might be helpful for figuring out how to test the property's type.