# How do I identify the return type of a method during runtime?

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa, dynamic, runtime

For the sake of this question, let us say that I have an Objective-C class consisting of the following methods:

```
- (float)method1;
- (CGPoint)method2;
- (NSString *)method3;
- (void)method4;
```

How can I identify the return types of all the methods above dynamically during runtime?

Comment: would recommend working through some basic Objective C tutorials before posting asking for help

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229777/way-to-get-return-type-of-a-method-in-objective-c answers your question

Comment: @bengoesboom, that question only addressees object returns (which you can't distinguish between). It is possible to get information about primitive return types with `method_getReturnType()`. A better discussion for this is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7447559/in-objective-c-how-to-find-out-the-return-type-of-a-method-via-reflection

Comment: That said, it is very unlikely that, as a rookie, you would want to do this in a real program. This kind of introspection is a very advanced topic. It is fine to study it and learn more about the runtime (you shouldn't be afraid of the runtime), but unless you're building meta-frameworks like test harnesses, it is very unlikely you should do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Objective-C runtime functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/objcruntimeref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418-CH3g-BBCCHBEI) to get this information, but there are limitations. The code below will do what you want:

```
Method method1 = class_getInstanceMethod([MyClass class], @selector(method1));
char * method1ReturnType = method_copyReturnType(method1);
NSLog(@"method1 returns: %s", method1ReturnType);
free(method4ReturnType);

Method method2 = class_getInstanceMethod([MyClass class], @selector(method2));
char * method2ReturnType = method_copyReturnType(method2);
NSLog(@"method2 returns: %s", method2ReturnType);
free(method4ReturnType);

Method method3 = class_getInstanceMethod([MyClass class], @selector(method3));
char * method3ReturnType = method_copyReturnType(method3);
NSLog(@"method3 returns: %s", method3ReturnType);
free(method4ReturnType);

Method method4 = class_getInstanceMethod([MyClass class], @selector(method4));
char * method4ReturnType = method_copyReturnType(method4);
NSLog(@"method4 returns: %s", method4ReturnType);
free(method4ReturnType);
```

Output:

```
>>method1 returns: f
>>method2 returns: {CGPoint=dd}
>>method3 returns: @
>>method4 returns: v
```

The string returned by `method_copyReturnType()` is an Objective-C type encoding string, [documented here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/objcruntimeref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418-CH3g-BBCCHBEI). Note that while you can tell if a method returns an object (encode string "@"), you can't tell what kind of object it is.

I'd be curious why you're interested in doing this. Especially for a new Objective-C programmer, my first inclination is to encourage you to think about whether this is actually a good design choice. For the methods you've asked about, this is pretty straightforward, but methods with more exotic return types can lead you into some trickier stuff with type encodings.

Comment: No problem, it's always fun to play around with the runtime.